# Wrap TLS connection in TLS connection

Tags: python, ssl, python-asyncio

I'm trying to wrap a TLS connection in a TLS connection using asyncio.
But I'm struggling to connect the outer and the inner connection.

What I tried:

```
async def inner_tls_client():
    inner_ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
    inner_reader, inner_writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
        host=inner_server_host,
        port=inner_server_port,
        ssl=inner_ssl_context
    )

    try:
        data = b"Hello, Inner Server!"
        inner_writer.write(data)
        await inner_writer.drain()

        received_data = await inner_reader.read(100)
        print(f"Received from Inner Server: {received_data.decode()}")

    finally:
        inner_writer.close()
        await inner_writer.wait_closed()


async def outer_tls_client():
    outer_ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)

    outer_reader, outer_writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
        host=outer_server_host,
        port=outer_server_port,
        ssl=outer_ssl_context
    )

    try:
        received_data = await outer_reader.read(100)
        print(f"Received from Outer Server: {received_data.decode()}")

        await inner_tls_client()

    finally:
        outer_writer.close()
        await outer_writer.wait_closed()
```

What should I do?

Comment: Why do you want to do that at all? TLS encrypts the connection end-to-end, not just to the next intermediate proxy or server. Are you trying to use the "outer" TLS connection as some kind of ad-hoc VPN?

Comment: Yes exactly like an ad-hoc VPN

Comment: You can't do it this way, at least not easily. VPN isn't just a TLS connection, it involves setting up routing and DNS so you can access the remote network's IPs and domain names. Why don't you use your VPN's client to start the the connection?

Comment: The server handle it... I'm doing that for practice

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: A common use case for this is a HTTPS connection over a proxy, where the connection to the proxy is TLS encrypted too. Many proxies support this, browsers support this too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich you don't need to do this to use an HTTPS proxy as just an HTTPS proxy. In this code the "inner" socket isn't using the "outer" one to connect, it's trying to connect directly to the internal IP, so it fails. There's no `context.wrap_socket`. I've done what you describe a very long time ago (10+ years), using stunnel so a certain bank wouldn't realize we were a 3-member algo trading team working out of a small brokerage with no experienced IT guy. `stunnel` takes care of routing itself though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: the use case of accessing a HTTP proxy with HTTPS is to hide the CONNECT request and inner TLS handshake (with the SNI) from the ISP. Kind of the same reason as using a VPN for privacy (and possible blocking) against the ISP, only for web traffic only instead all network traffic.